# Dynamic Logic in Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel workbook which has 30 worksheets in it. Each sheet looks something like this

[image]

Now i want to insert a column after "I" column (the new column will be J)and the values should be some thing like this

for coupon 2.000(4-7 rows) the values in the new column J should be =  i4-i5(For all J4,5,6,7)
This should be repeated for each coupon.
I tried recording the macro but did not help.
Please provide **me sample logic** to handle this dynamically.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code at all?  Your picture doesn't show up.

Comment: @TIM....I am sorry ....dont know what i have done wrong so that the image did not pop up....i will try reloading it again..check n let me know if it is viewable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it sounded like this is what you are looking for. Please let me know if that is not the case.

```
Sub AddNewColumn()
    Dim sColumnToIns, sCouponField, sCouponGroup, _
        sFormula, sCell1, sCell2, sMarketValueField, sColumnToInsHeader, sTopCellOfData
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim oSh As Worksheet

    'Make sure you change the sheet to reflect
    'the object name of your sheet.
    Set oSh = Sheet2
    sColumnToIns = "J"
    sColumnToInsHeader = "New Column"
    sCouponField = "B"
    sMarketValueField = "I"
    sTopCellOfData = "A4"


    'Insert a new column
    Sheet1.Range(sColumnToIns & ":" & sColumnToIns).Insert xlShiftToRight

    'Get lowest cell in used range
    Set rRng = oSh.UsedRange.Cells(oSh.UsedRange.Rows.Count, oSh.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
    Set rData = oSh.Range(sTopCellOfData, rRng)

    'Set the header text
    rData.Range(sColumnToIns & "1").Offset(-1).Value = sColumnToInsHeader

    'Go through the entire data set. Whenever the value in the 'Coupon'
    'column changes, put a formula the subtracts the top market value
    'from the next market value down.
    sCouponGroup = ""
    For Each rCell In rData.Columns(sCouponField).Cells
        If sCouponGroup <> rCell.Value Then
            sCouponGroup = rCell.Value
            sCell1 = rCell.EntireRow.Columns(sMarketValueField).Address
            sCell2 = rCell.EntireRow.Columns(sMarketValueField).Offset(1).Address
            sFormula = "=" & sCell1 & "-" & sCell2
        End If

        rCell.EntireRow.Columns(sColumnToIns).Formula = sFormula
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks transistor.....you were half the way....but gave me a good sample...I will try this

Comment: Any time! Please let me know if you need any more help with it.